# Getting Blue Screen code("Driver Power State Failure") when updating or installing windows 10 and High CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, cpu-usage

**Edit: Fixed the issue**
The issue was of incompatible hdd caddy. Changed the caddy for a new one. The blue screen error and the System process using too much cpu both got fixed.

Whenever I try to update or install Windows 10 I get this blue screen sometime once sometime multiple times. The error code I get on blue screen is:

> Driver Power State Failure

Then after sometimes the Windows boots up normally.

Now after installing Windows I see `System` process using too much CPU like 15-30% sometimes.
Is it related to that Blue Screen error or some other issue?

[image: Task manager screenshot]

Using process explorer I got that ACPI.sys is using CPU.

[image: process explorer screenshot]

[image: blue screen error]

Comment: Try the advice in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1635684/8672).

Comment: @harrymc did chkdsk and got: Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

Comment: @harrymc I have latest 20h2 version installed using iso. Should I do the inplace upgrade of same version from within the window? I previouly did was install windows 1709 and then later updated to 20h2 using iso file from within the window

Comment: Do first the other advice in my linked answer.

Comment: @harrymc they showed no error

Comment: Before trying the inplace upgrade (carefully), see if in the folder `C:\Windows\Minidump` you have a `.dmp` file dating from the crash. If you do, analyze it, or if you want me to have a look, zip it and post it online (dropbox or any other).

Comment: @harrymc there is no Minidump folder

Comment: Impossible - perhaps it's hidden. Otherwise, inplace upgrade may help.

Comment: @harrymc checked show hidden files. In C\Windows there is no folder with name Minidump even hidden one

Comment: If you get another BSOD, take a screenshot with your phone.

Comment: @harrymc edited into the post check now

Comment: A driver apparently entered sleep and didn't respond. It's sometimes symptomatic of a bad driver. Check for recent enough drivers on the manufacturer's website for the motherboard and GPU. Another try is to run *Power Options > Choose what the power button does > Change settings that are currently unavailable* and turn off "fast startup (recommended)". Lastly, boot in Safe mode and retry the upgrade.

Comment: @harrymc The issue was of incompatible caddy which had my hdd. Changed the caddy and it got fixed. Thanks for help though

Comment: Bad hardware would be indistinguishable from a bad driver.

Answer (score 0):

ACPI.sys is a driver for power management, PnP devices, USB etc.
And DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE is an error often linked to corrupted drivers.
FIX?: Go into "Device Manager" and look for a driver with a exclamation mark. That driver should be the problem.

To fix the problem try updating the driver.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no driver with exclamation mark. Plus whenever i update a driver it shows already on latest version

Comment: Well at least one of your drivers is problematic, try to find it and disable/replace it.

Comment: on process explorer it shows acp.sys how to find which one is problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps performed in the link given below. I hope it solves your problem.
**https://computerverge.com/driver-power-state-failure/**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1196123)

Comment: This link doesn't answer the question. It's just a link to generic article on the topic that the internet is filled with only to get AD impressions and clicks.