# Windows 10 won't sleep - no requests, no wake_armed, no waketimers

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, power-management, powercfg

Something broke my Windows system so it won't sleep automatically. The Monitor goes out after the period set, but the PC stays awake.

`powercfg -requests` - everything NONE

`powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` - Keyboard and network card. I have turned both of them off so the list was empty, the PC was still awake, so I have turned them back on, because I need Wake on Lan.

`powercfg -waketimers` - empty

`powercfg -lastwake` - only the Power Button, that is probably the Wake on Lan funtion. I wasn't expecting here something else, because if I put the PC on sleep it stays that way untill I wake it manually.

`powercfg -energy` - test runs, in the report nothing is preventing sleep.

Drivers, Windows 10, everything is up to date. Media Sharing is not allowed to prevent sleep. I have Plex Media Server, which can keep the server awake, but if it's running it shows on the -requests list.

I have tried an AutoHotkey script found [in this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1633518/windows-10-desktop-pc-will-not-go-to-sleep-automatically-based-on-set-idle-timer?rq=1). This script was reporting whether or not the idle timer is being constantly reset when there's no input. The idle timer is not resetting until the point where the monitor goes out, after that I can't see it.

Do you guys have any tips?

Comment: It might be worth something, for me to say that, I just came across this post, having run all the checks you have, and my laptop also isn't going to sleep. It used to work a while ago, I did nothing™, and now it won't sleep. Why is there no check that can see why? I can add that: idle + screensaver works. And this machine was never set to use modern standby (and the energy test confirms it)

Comment: Update - just figured it out. It was an intermittent THX Spatial Audio that shows up in powercfg -requests, SOMETIMES. That piece of *! Though the only reason it works like that, is because MS Windows forces it to constantly listen to the default audio device and apply spatial audio on top like on a virtual line-in.