# How can I find out what is preventing the screen from locking?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

My wife's computer with Windows 10 won't honor the screen timeout settings in Settings/Power and Sleep.  Specifically, what happens is that the screen blanks for less than a second and then the screen comes back on. (And yes, the system won't sleep, either.)

If I explicitly tell the computer to sleep, it goes to sleep as expected.

I've checked the usual settings issues, and I've come to the tentative conclusion that one of the apps she's running is vetoing the sleep request.

Any ideas on how to figure out *which* app is causing this behavior?

Comment: I understand you want the machine to go to sleep automatically.  If you are able to put the machine to sleep manually that means there isn't an application that is preventing the machine from automatically going to sleep.  This means the machine is never attempting to go into that sleep state.  I have some additional thoughts, but don't have access to my notes, I will be asking for more information shortly.

Comment: Related but not a dupe - https://superuser.com/questions/1576236/simple-windows-10-view-of-any-process-preventing-sleep Higher rep users may be able to check if the deleted answers would be appropriate here [idk Win well enough to decide]. Empirically, things like radio stations & youtube will keep awake.

Comment: As it turns out, it appears that the problem was caused by some sort of Microsoft Account issue.  I contacted Microsoft support on a separate issue, which resulted in the power behavior going away.

Answer (score 9):

To view which applications are preventing just use the command (Using CMD with Admin rights):

```
powercfg /requests
```

And you will know the process.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Settings > System > Power & sleep` and look up on the settings.

Windows 10 default settings:
[image]

Change your settings like this.

Comment: As I said in the original message, I've checked those settings.   The machine isn't honoring those settings.